# Sorting By Checking the Option Button PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I want to let the user sort the table base on what the user wants.
I have two options for this, *sort by name* or *sort by exam*.

code

```
echo "<table border=1 align=center><tr class=style2><td><input type=radio name=sort value='byname'>Sort By Name<td><input type=radio name=sort value='byexam'>Sort By Exam";

$sort = $_POST['name'];
if ($sort == "byname"){
    $sort=mysql_query("select * from mst_adminresult order by login ASC",$cn) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sort))
    echo "<table border=1 align=center><tr class=style2><td>Student Name <td> Test<br> Question <td> Score";
    echo "<tr class=style8><td>$row[1] <td align=center> $row[2] <td align=center> $row[3]/20";
    echo "</table>";

}else{
    $sort=mysql_query("select * from mst_adminresult order by test_id ASC",$cn) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sort))
    echo "<table border=1 align=center><tr class=style2><td>Exam<td width=300>Student Name<td> Score";
    echo "<tr class=style8><td>$row[1] <td align=center> $row[2] <td align=center> $row[3]/20";
    echo "</table>";
}

echo "<table border=1 align=center><tr class=style2><td width=300>Student Name <td> Test<br> Question <td> Score";

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs))
{
echo "<tr class=style8><td>$row[1] <td align=center> $row[2] <td align=center> $row[3]/20";
}
echo "</table>";
```

the problem I am encountering is it doesn't function properly. The default arrangement of the data is listed by the latest exam taker to the last. Now what I am aiming for is, if the user checks the *by the name* option, it will sort by name. for the *by exam*, it will be listed by exam.

output:
[image]

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: Your select has `name="sort"`, yet you check `$_POST['name']` later. Change this to `$_POST['sort']`.

Comment: it works fine..but the layout is in mess... i'll edit the question so that everyone can see the layout. it should just be one table @GeraldSchneider

Answer (score 1):

Your input radio button `name="sort"` so you need to use `$_POST['sort']`.

You can use input value as database field name so that we can easily use it in query without if...else condition.

```
echo "<table border=1 align=center><tr class=style2>
     <tr><td><input type=radio name='sort' value='byname'>Sort By Name</td>
     <td><input type=radio name='sort' value='byexam'>Sort By Exam</td></tr></table>";

$sort = isset($_POST['sort']) ? $_POST['sort'] : "test_id"; // change of $_POST['name'] to $_POST['sort']

$sortQuery = mysql_query("select * from mst_adminresult order by ".$sort." ASC",$cn) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sortQuery))
{
    echo "<table border=1 align=center><tr class=style2><td>Student Name</td><td>Test<br> Question</td><td>Score</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=style8><td>$row[1]</td> <td align=center> $row[2]</td> <td align=center> ". ($row[3]/20) ."</td></tr> ";
    echo "</table>";
}

echo "<table border=1 align=center><tr class=style2><td width=300>Student Name</td><td> Test<br> Question </td><td> Score</td></tr>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs))
{
echo "<tr class=style8><td>$row[1]</td> <td align=center> $row[2]</td> <td align=center> ". ($row[3]/20) ."</td></tr> ";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: it works fine..but the layout is in mess... i'll edit the question so everyone can see...
it should just be one table only

Comment: Try edited code and let me know your output. @Jennifer

Comment: And say hello to MySQL injection.. Don't use `mysql_` since the functions are deprecated. And if you use the above code anyways, at least add `mysql_real_escape_string` to your `$_POST` data.